# Error trying to create Facbeook test user through API

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a Facebook test user with this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/MY_APP_ID/accounts/test-users?installed=true&name=TEST_1&locale=en_US&permissions=email,user_events,friends_birthday,xmpp_login,read_mailbox&method=post&access_token=MY_APP_ID|SOME_HASH
```

The app access token is freshly generated.

My app is of type "Native iOS App"

The error I'm receiving is not so specific:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seemed like it was a temporary bug, I just tried with the same query now and it was successful.

**EDIT:** Or.... It still might be a bug... seems that in the `name` argument you can't have numbers.